Cannot find a working graphic adapter for VBox Ubuntu machine
On my Ubuntu 24.04 I created a fresh virtual machine with virtual box, with Ubuntu 24.04 too.
Since the very first start I experience a lot of hangs of the machine. Inspecting the dmesg I find this:
[drm] *ERROR* vmwgfx seems to be running on an unsupported hypervisor.
[drm] *ERROR* This configuration is likely broken.
[drm] *ERROR* Please switch to a supported graphics device to avoid problems.

and a lot of this:
[drm:vmw_msg_ioctl [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to open channel.

Not sure if it's related but also:
[    3.229706] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    3.229709] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 577 at kernel/rcu/tree_plugin.h:734 rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x3ad/0x3c0
[    3.229716] Modules linked in: sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel crypto_simd vmwgfx(+) drm_ttm_helper cryptd vboxguest(OE) joydev ttm i2c_piix4 input_leds serio_raw mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul ahci psmouse libahci e1000 video pata_acpi wmi
[    3.229747] CPU: 4 PID: 577 Comm: (udev-worker) Tainted: G           OE      6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu
[    3.229749] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[    3.229751] RIP: 0010:rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x3ad/0x3c0
[    3.229754] Code: 04 25 40 43 03 00 f0 80 08 08 65 81 25 20 19 e5 70 ff ff ff 7f e9 a2 fe ff ff 8b 87 38 08 00 00 85 c0 0f 84 23 fd ff ff eb b2 <0f> 0b e9 ed fc ff ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 90 90 90
[    3.229760] RSP: 0018:ffffbed1c01d4e68 EFLAGS: 00010086
[    3.229762] RAX: ffff97cec5580000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[    3.229764] RDX: 00000000ffffffff RSI: ffffffff90bddf1c RDI: ffff97cec5580000
[    3.229765] RBP: ffffbed1c01d4e80 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[    3.229767] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[    3.229768] R13: ffff97d1d8c25000 R14: ffffbed1c103b898 R15: ffff97d1d8c24ac0
[    3.229770] FS:  00007a9cf16188c0(0000) GS:ffff97d1d8c00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    3.229771] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    3.229773] CR2: 00005ca2018a7458 CR3: 0000000104c42000 CR4: 00000000000506f0
[    3.229777] Call Trace:
[    3.229778]  <IRQ>
[    3.229781]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[    3.229785]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[    3.229789]  ? rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x3ad/0x3c0
[    3.229792]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[    3.229796]  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
[    3.229800]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[    3.229803]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[    3.229810]  ? rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x3ad/0x3c0
[    3.229812]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229815]  update_process_times+0x76/0xb0
[    3.229819]  tick_sched_handle+0x28/0x70
[    3.229826]  tick_nohz_highres_handler+0x78/0xa0
[    3.229828]  ? __pfx_tick_nohz_highres_handler+0x10/0x10
[    3.229831]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x112/0x2a0
[    3.229834]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229837]  hrtimer_interrupt+0xf6/0x250
[    3.229841]  __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x51/0x150
[    3.229845]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x8d/0xd0
[    3.229847]  </IRQ>
[    3.229848]  <TASK>
[    3.229850]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1b/0x20
[    3.229852] RIP: 0010:sock_poll+0x34/0x100
[    3.229856] Code: 57 41 56 41 55 49 89 fd 41 54 53 4c 8b a7 c8 00 00 00 48 89 f3 4d 8b 7c 24 20 48 85 f6 0f 84 b7 00 00 00 8b 76 08 49 8b 4f 40 <31> c0 48 85 c9 74 22 49 8b 54 24 18 44 8b b2 10 01 00 00 45 85 f6
[    3.229858] RSP: 0018:ffffbed1c103b948 EFLAGS: 00000282
[    3.229860] RAX: ffffffff8fec3f10 RBX: ffffbed1c103b9d0 RCX: ffffffff8fee41a0
[    3.229861] RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 0000000000000019 RDI: ffff97cec506f800
[    3.229863] RBP: ffffbed1c103b970 R08: ffff97cec9d5fa18 R09: 0000000000000000
[    3.229864] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff97cec89d9040
[    3.229865] R13: ffff97cec506f800 R14: ffff97cec9d5fa00 R15: ffffffff90777ec0
[    3.229868]  ? __pfx_sock_poll+0x10/0x10
[    3.229870]  ? __pfx_datagram_poll+0x10/0x10
[    3.229875]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229878]  ep_item_poll.isra.0+0x57/0xb0
[    3.229882]  ep_send_events+0x178/0x2a0
[    3.229890]  ep_poll+0x16b/0x390
[    3.229894]  do_epoll_wait+0xdb/0x100
[    3.229898]  __x64_sys_epoll_wait+0x6f/0x110
[    3.229902]  x64_sys_call+0x18af/0x25c0
[    3.229905]  do_syscall_64+0x7f/0x180
[    3.229908]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229910]  ? vfs_write+0x3d6/0x480
[    3.229915]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229917]  ? ksys_write+0xc9/0x100
[    3.229919]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229921]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[    3.229924]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229926]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.229931]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229933]  ? __sys_sendmsg+0x89/0xf0
[    3.229937]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229939]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[    3.229942]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229943]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.229946]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229948]  ? __fput_sync+0x1c/0x30
[    3.229953]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229955]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229956]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[    3.229959]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229961]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.229963]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229973]  ? __fput_sync+0x1c/0x30
[    3.229975]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229976]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229978]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[    3.229981]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229983]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.229984]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229986]  ? __x64_sys_openat+0x55/0xa0
[    3.229989]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229991]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[    3.229993]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229995]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.229997]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0xfbef5
[    3.229999]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[    3.230001]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[    3.230003]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[    3.230006] RIP: 0033:0x7a9cf152a007
[    3.230015] Code: 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 b8 ff ff ff ff eb be 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 45 10 0e 00 00 41 89 ca 74 10 b8 e8 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 20 89 55 f8 48 89
[    3.230017] RSP: 002b:00007ffc55eac828 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e8
[    3.230019] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 00007a9cf152a007
[    3.230020] RDX: 0000000000000006 RSI: 00006098dd36d0f0 RDI: 000000000000001f
[    3.230022] RBP: 00007ffc55eac940 R08: 00006098dd200010 R09: 0000000000000007
[    3.230023] R10: 00000000ffffffff R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000014
[    3.230024] R13: 00006098dd248778 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: 00006098dd2485e0
[    3.230028]  </TASK>
[    3.230030] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---

I tried to select all the options for graphics in VBox:

VMSVGA
VBoxVGA
VBoxSVGA

but in any case I found the same error lines.
Reading through this thread I tried to install xserver-xorg-video-vmware but it was already there.
I tried to switch on and off the 3d acceleration flag, it seems does nothing.
I also tried to disable Wayland.
What else can I do?
I have never had problems of this type with VirtualBox.
